# DB2 Sql - How to join a table on a resulting field of another table

Tags: sql, join, db2

I'm trying to join two tables but I can't join `field1` of `table1` with `field2` of `table2` which is the result of a `DISTINCT` instruction.

e.g.

```
Select f1
From   table1 
join (Select distinct(f2) as "secondField"
      From table2
     ) b on f1 = *X*
```

What can I set as `X`? Maybe `b.f2` or `b.secondField` ?

If `X` is a specific field I've got no problem, if it is given by a DISTINCT, SUM or similar functions I'm not able to manage it.

Can someone give me a tip?

Comment: Thank you guys for helping me, I'll try your suggestion asap.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT f1 
FROM table1 a
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT(f2) as "secondField" FROM table2) b
  ON a.f1 = b.secondField
```

Will get what you're looking for. Since you gave a specific name inside the sub-query, that's what you'd use (and what you would *have* to use, since you're using the `DISTINCT`).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried joining on `secondfield`? Please see the following:

```
Select f1
From   table1 
join (Select distinct(f2) as "secondField"
      From table2
    ) b on b.secondField = table1.f1
```

Simply if you are using an aggregate function such as Distinct, Count, Max, etc. in a sub-query, give the aggregate an alias and use this alias in the join statement.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you are trying to do might be written simpler as:

```
SELECT f1 
FROM table1 a
WHERE  f1 IN (SELECT f2 as "secondField" FROM table2)
```

Or

```
SELECT f1 
FROM table1 a
WHERE  f1 IN (SELECT DISTINCT(f2) as "secondField" FROM table2)
```

One of these may be faster than your JOIN